# how to show complete sql string in kohana orm object?

Tags: sql, kohana, orm

this is probably trivial, but i have a quite long sql query and echo Kohana::debug( $obj ); cuts off the tail of the query, replacing it with '...'.

how would i go about getting the full thing?
(something nicer than var_dump if possible ;-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the Profiler. For Kohana 3, put this in your template:

```
<div id="kohana-profiler">
<?php echo View::factory('profiler/stats') ?>
</div>
```

If you're using Kohana 2, just load the library in your controller:

```
$this->profiler = new Profiler;
```

The profiler dumps details of timing, post, cookies, sessions and database queries.

Comment: nice one! didn't know that (obiously)